# What does record name in list view, view/edit form mean

Tags: dev401

I am new to Salesforce and actively studying and preparing for Dev401 Certification. When I am reading through the dumps, I am encountering this question:

Which record name will be used in list view, view/edit form?
A.  Record name changed by 'App Setup -> Customize'
B.  Record name changed by 'App Setup -> Create -> Objects'

The recommended answer is B but I don't think I understand the question. What does record name in list view, view/edit form mean? I am assuming that list view is under the correspondent tab and record name is the first column that displays. E.g. Opportunity name if the tab is Opportunity. But I can't find view/edit form.

Would anyone please advise where under Setup -> Customize can I customize this and what it is?

Answer (score 1):

have you been there already? in that page you can modify some information of the selected object like: label, plural label, Object Name and Record Name.

Record Name is the field that is going to be used to search or identify those records, you can select auto-number or text.

Auto number example (field is read only):
Acct-001
Acct-002

Text:
Acme 
Salesforce

Hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Like @Emilio is saying in his answer, in Salesforce each Object has a standard Record Name field.  From the [help page](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=dev_objectcreate.htm&language=en_US):

> `Record Name`: The name used in page layouts, list views, related lists, and search results.

This can be edited on the Object by going to **App Setup | Create | Objects**.

It makes sense that the 'B' option is the correct choice.

The view "form" is the record detail page and the "edit" form is the record edit page (e.g., what gets displayed when you hit the Edit button on the detail page).

Under Customize you can change the tab names and labels, so perhaps that is what the other option is referring to or perhaps it is referring to something that doesn't exist since it is not actually the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your inputs. And sorry that there might be a typo in my original post. The suggested answer is A, not B. This answer was provided on two different websites, though I am still not quite sure whether it is correct.

I fairly understand what you say and sorry about any misunderstandings. I hear what you say about the the record names and I know that for custom objects/tabs, I should use create object/edit field to update it. However, I am not quite sure what the question is asking about record name in list view, view/edit? Does that mean the tab name shown in the each tab?

Thanks,
Lance

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your inputs again. I did some tries and am pretty convinced that the correct answer should be A now. Even though, I still found it quite helpful with your guys' inputs which helped me in finding the way out.

Here is what I did: 
1. Create a new custom object named Position and make the record name Position title. (So position title is the record name under create -> Object
2. Customize -> Tab names and Labels -> Rename Tabs and Labels. Find the Position tab and change the record name into Job titles. 
3. Go back to Create -> Object, check position object. Verify that the record name is still Position title.
4. Go to Position tab. Look at the record name. It is Job titles.

So I guess what the question is asking is about when the record names are different under customization and create -> object, which one will be shown. And the record name, here literally means the 'column name', instead of each record's name. In this case, it is Position titles/Job titles, not  {JB-000001}.